# C# volatile usage for struct fields accessed from different threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, volatile

I am writing a library with task-like types for handling async/await code, to get a better understanding of how Tasks work in .NET under the hood.

What bothers me is the situation when multiple threads are accessing the same struct fields, where reading most recent and writing values immediately is crucial for the correctness of whole operation.

```cs
struct TaskLike
{
    private SynchronizationContext? _syncContext;

    private SpinLock _completionLock;
    private volatile bool _hasCompleted;
    private volatile Action _continuation;
    private Exception? _exception;

    public void GetResult()
    {
        if (_exception != null)
            throw _exception;
    }

    public void Complete(Exception? ex)
    {
        _exception = ex;

        bool lockTaken = false;
        _completionLock.Enter(ref lockTaken);

        _hasCompleted = true;
        var cont = _continuation;

        _completionLock.Exit();

        if (cont != null)
        {
            if (_synchronizationContext != null)
                _synchronizationContext.Post(cont, null);
            else
                cont.Invoke();
        }
    }

    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
    {
        bool lockTaken = false;
        _completionLock.Enter(ref lockTaken);

        _continuation = continuation;
        bool immediateInvoke = _hasCompleted && _ex == null;

        _completionLock.Exit();

        if (immediateInvoke)
            continuation.Invoke();
    }
}
```

While this code seems to be working even for millions of iterations, I am not sure if it is **guaranteed** to work.

Therefore, few questions about it:

1. Is it guaranteed, that if two threads call `Complete()` and `OnCompleted()` simultenaously, only one thread will invoke continuation? From my understanding, this is where `volatile` helps and is necessary. In other case, it is possible that cache may not be flushed after exiting `_completionLock`, so the other thread may see outdated data. Is that correct?
2. Instead of `volatile`, can I use `Volatile.Read(ref field)` and `Volatile.Write(ref field, value)` inside `_completionLock` in both methods? Will the effect be the same?
3. Should `_exception` be `volatile` as well? Let's assume that `GetResult()` will be called from `continuation`:

   1. When invoked from `OnComplete()`, there is no problem, as the `_exception` has to be null.
   2. When invoked from `Complete()`, if `_synchronizationContext` is null, then `GetResult()` is executed from the same thread (so no problem). **But** in the other case, is it possible that very unfortunate interleaving executes `continuation` inside `SynchronizationContext` on other thread, before current thread flushes `_exception` value? Or maybe `_exception` is flushed when `_completionLock` is entered, or `_hasCompleted` written? This is the part I'm not sure about.